# Phusion Passenger 5.1.11 doesn't recognize --start-timeout option

Tags: ruby, passenger

According to the blog https://blog.phusion.nl/2017/10/16/passenger-5-1-11/

> [Standalone] passenger start now accepts the --start-timeout configuration option.

I have passenger gem installed and it has a version: "Phusion Passenger 5.1.11".

But, when I run `passenger start --start-timeout 300` it says:
`*** ERROR: invalid option: --start-timeout`

Is there a way to make --start-timeout option work? Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an enterprise-only flag. The release announcement should have been more clear.